# Timer Trigger Function running long process with Azure Function App with COMSUMPTION plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to develop a process (e.g. Azure fucntion app) that will load a file from FTP once every week, and perform ETL and update to other service for a long time (100mins).

My question is that will Timer Trigger Azure Function app with COMSUMPTION plan works in this scenario, given that the max running time of Azure function app is 10 mins.

**Update**

My theory of using Timer trigger function with Comumption plan is that if the timer is set to wake up every 4 mins from certain period (e.g. 5am - 10am Monday only), and within the function, a status tells whether or not an existing processing is in progress. If it is, the process continues its on-going job, otherwise, the function exits.

Is it doable or any flaw?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your exact scenario, but I would consider one of the following options:

### Option 1

Use durable functions. ([Here is a C# example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp))

It will allow you to start your process and while you wait for different tasks to complete, your function won't actually be running.

---

### Option2

In case durable functions doesn't suit your needs, you can try to use a combination of a timer triggered function and [ACI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) with your logic.

In a nutshell, your flow should looks something like this:

1. Timer function is triggered
2. Call an API to create the ACI
3. End of timer function.
4. The service in the ACI starts his job
5. After the service is done, it calls an API to remove it's own ACI.

---

But in anyway, durable functions usually do the trick.
Let me know if something is unclear.
Good luck. :)

Comment: Where is your process running? What are you monitoring?
What would like to do if the process is actually running?

Comment: My process is running as a timer trigger function app as mentioned on OP. Monitoring? Process needs to load csv file, perform ETL job, and based on the ETL data update IoT DPS, which has speed throttling. This is why the function takes long time. The function app needs to be running during this period.

Comment: Ok, so since your process itself is a long running once, I would go with option 2.
The trigger should check if the ACI is up and running (Which means that the process is still ongoing) and if so, do nothing.
If the ACI is not running, based on your needs, you can start it up, which in turn will begin the process.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a simple timer trigger function is not your option, and option 1?

Comment: From what I understand, you process might take up to 100 minutes, which is far more than the allowed 10 minutes. That leaves you with another option of creating a service which will run and handle your logic. Since you said you want this process to happen once a week, you don't really need a container up a running for the whole week.
Creating a durable timer function which fire up your ACI and monitor it seems to be the most cost efficient option.

Comment: Is durable function also restricted to max execution of 10 mins? even using `OrchestrationTrigger` and `ActivityTrigger`?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/dev/samples/precompiled/HelloSequence.cs

Comment: Durable functions don't run while they wait for something to execute. So if you can divide your work to smaller chunks and make sure they don't exceed the max execution time, you basically can run a bunch of Azure functions triggered by your durable timer function.

Comment: I have questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547349/orchestrationtrigger-durable-function-input-and-execution-time-with-await-with

Answer (score 0):

With Consumptions plan, the azure function can run for max 10 minutes, still, you need to configure in host.json

You can go for the App Service Plan which has no time limit. Again you need to configure function timeout property in host.json

**for more seed the following tutorial**
https://sps-cloud-architect.blogspot.com/2019/12/azure-data-load-etl-process-using-azure.html